# Background CSS property doesn't seem to work correctly

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm a novice in html and css, I got a problem regarding this code.
Basically what I/m trying to do is to put a background image in the back of every section ( the image should fit perfectly the section). With this kind of code nothing happend, I can just change color to te section. there is no error in the path image so I'm a little bit confused.

```css
#logo {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 190px;
}

#logo1 {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 190px;
  z-index: 3;
}

header {
  z-index: 2;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "ChicagoFLF", sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  z-index: 1
}

h2 {
  font-family: "ChicagoFLF", sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: -15px;
}

h3 {
  font-family: "ChicagoFLF", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: -15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


}
#back1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url('asset/background1.png');
}
#back2 {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url('asset/background1.png');
}
#back3 {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url('asset/background1.png');
}
.onepage {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  q
}
.more {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1000px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#push {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 130px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 47%;
}
#pushtext {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 46%;
}
#pushtext1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 46%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/onepage.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js" integrity="sha256-siFczlgw4jULnUICcdm9gjQPZkw/YPDqhQ9+nAOScE4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/onepage.js"></script>
  <title>One Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div id="logo"><img id="logo1" src="asset/logoblack.png" alt=""></div>
    <h1>
      Andrea Lovati
    </h1>
    <h2>
      some text
    </h2>
  </header>
  <!--first section-->
  <section class="onepage" id="back1">
    <div id="pushtext">
      <a href="#second">
        <h3>discover more</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="push"><img src="asset/push.png"></div>
  </section>
  <!--second section-->
  <div id="back2">
  </div>
  <!--third section-->
  <section id="back3">
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the background image needs to be relative to the css file (if those styles are inside the onepage.css), so I'm guessing your path should be `../asset/background1.png` (unless your asset folder is inside the css folder)

Comment: Are your HTML and CSS on the same page just like on this code?

Comment: If the images are in the right place and you're still not seeing them it could be that height 100%; is not working, try changing it with height: 100vh; which means 100 viewport height, so it makes as tall as the browser window, regardless of the parent element.

Comment: Can you make a screenshot or type your file structure. I think you are trying to access the images from the place where the CSS file is located. 

-- assets
  -- images
  -- css
  -- js

You might want to check your directory structure to see what the correct path is to your image.

../assets/images/image.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue with the background-image url. When you say

```
background-image: url('asset/background1.png');
```

You are telling your browser to wherever the css file is, this is a relative path from it. Let's say the css file name is:

- myclasses.css

Given what you said, the containing folder should be looking like this:

- myclasses.css  --> Your css file
- asset  --> Folder

Now the "asset" folder MUST contain background1.png.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your time. I've solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The most important error is that you have a superflous closing `}` curly bracket in your CSS, directly befor the rule for `back1`. Delete that:

```css
#logo {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 190px;
}

#logo1 {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 190px;
  z-index: 3;
}

header {
  z-index: 2;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "ChicagoFLF", sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  z-index: 1
}

h2 {
  font-family: "ChicagoFLF", sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: -15px;
}

h3 {
  font-family: "ChicagoFLF", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: -15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#back1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/600x450/cf9?text=back1);
}
#back2 {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/600x450/9fc?text=back2);
}
#back3 {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/600x450/fc9?text=back3);
}
.onepage {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.more {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1000px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#push {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 130px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 47%;
}
#pushtext {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 46%;
}
#pushtext1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 46%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="logo"><img id="logo1" src="asset/logoblack.png" alt=""></div>
  <h1>
    Andrea Lovati
  </h1>
  <h2>
    some text
  </h2>
</header>
<!--first section-->
<section class="onepage" id="back1">
  <div id="pushtext">
    <a href="#second">
      <h3>discover more</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="push"><img src="asset/push.png"></div>
</section>
<!--second section-->
<div id="back2">
</div>
<!--third section-->
<section id="back3">
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem with the image as well, so what I did was, place the img and the css file in the same assets folder. Then to link the css on html just write "". And for the background-image on css, just write "background-image: your-image.png". That's what I made to manage that. And to make the image fit perfectly on the section use "background-size: cover" on each section.